# To whom voting belongs to?

Tags: discussion, voting

Does the voting icon appearing in front of every question and answer belongs to the user who posted that, or to the question or particular answer itself?

Comment: Would it be cliché to say that the only dumb question is the one you don't ask? Probably...

Comment: ...also incorrect. I mean, there's all the dumb questions *i* ask, for starters...

Comment: Too many "to's" in the question.

Comment: Not enough punctuation either.

Answer (score 2):

The votes apply to the specific question or answer that it is next to.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the https://stackoverflow.com/faq, it explains..

> Here's how it works: if you post a good question or helpful answer, it will be voted up by your peers: you gain **10** reputation points. If you post something that's off topic or incorrect, it will be voted down: you lose **2** reputation points. You can earn up to **200** reputation per day, but no more. (Note that votes for any posts marked "community wiki" do not generate reputation.)

Comment: that 200 rep per day limit does not count bounties won or accepted answers won after the rep limit was reached

Comment: so what does this infers? voting is done for user or for question/answers ?

Comment: Voting is applied to questions/answers, but the reputation goes to the user who originally posted the question or answer.

Answer (score 1):

The voting icon on a question represents voting for the question.

The voting icon on each particular answer represents voting for the answer.

Comment: well i m  still confused.. then how does user gets it reputation? i mean where do u vote for the user?

Comment: Reputation is the total score you get from up and down votes (and other bonuses) for questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

The up/down vote arrows are for scoring the question or answer they are next to.

Reputation gain/loss from clicking the arrows applies to the user who created that question/answer.

Only exception is Community Wiki questions or answers, where no one gains or loses any reputation., but the arrows are still for scoring that specific post.